# How to get elements with xpath

Tags: python, xpath

How on python with xpath make this code

```
<span>
<span>Hi</span>
"."
<span> My</span>
<span> name </span>
"is"
<span> test</span>
</span>
```

to this

```
Hi. My name is test
```

Comment: show what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by this

```
page.xpath(".//span/child::node()")
```